# PHPExcel file cannot open because the file format or file extension is not valid

Tags: php, wordpress, phpexcel

I  developed wordpress plugin to export custom post content to excel file using PHPExcel library and everything works fine at my local machine when I uploaded the plugin to the server this error appears when I open the excel file

```
file cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid
```

I opened the excel file in notepad to see what is the error, I found this

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php on line 637
```

php version running on the server 5.3.28-1

how can I fix this

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd obviously pulled this from github fairly recently (sometime between 19 and 5 days ago) and are running PHP <= 5.4.0

This was an instance of short array syntax (only available after PHP 5.4.0) being used in code that was added to the repository 19 days ago. Realising the mistake, it was fixed in the repository 5 days ago.

If you pull from github now, you should not have this problem